# RevolverJS consolelog for currentSlide returns undefined

Tags: jquery

Im working on a website at the moment and have chosen to use the RevoloverJS plugin as it fits my current needs perfectly.

However i am trying to to get the current slide number to output to the firebug console and instead or returning a number it just returns undefined.

Below is the code i have so far. The alerts don't appear and the console log just returns undefined.

## Slider code

```
$('#slider').revolver({
    transition: {
        onStart: function(){
            var current = $('#slider').data('goto');
            if (current == '0'){
                alert('slide 0');
            }else if(current == '1'){
                alert('slide 1');
            }else if(current == '2'){
                alert('slide 2');
            }else if(current == '3'){
                alert('slide 3');
            }
            console.log(slider.currentSlide);
        },
        onFinish: function(){

        }
    }
});

var revolver = $('#slider').data('revolver');
$('.goto').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    revolver.goTo($(this).data('goto'));
});
```

I only have 4 images in the slider and am using the if statements to change the styling of some buttons on the page. Currently im just trying to get the alerts to work before I progress to changing the CSS. Much help would be appreciated apologies if I have made any noobish mistakes :)

Comment: do you define 'slider' anywhere? Have you tried 'revolver.currentSlide'?

Comment: an epic facepalm moment for me xD thank you very much. all fixed now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem now! turned out I was using slider and not revolver.

Working code for those who are interested. Thanks [matpol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115965/matpol) for the help!

```
$('#slider').revolver({
    transition: {
        onStart: function(){
            var current = revolver.currentSlide;
            if (current == 0){
                alert('slide 0');
            }else if(current == 1){
                alert('slide 1');
            }else if(current == 2){
                alert('slide 2');
            }else if(current == 3){
                alert('slide 3');
            }
            console.log(revolver.currentSlide);
        },
        onFinish: function(){

        }
    }
});

var revolver = $('#slider').data('revolver');
$('.goto').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    revolver.goTo($(this).data('goto'));
});
```